# Extension of Field Monomorphism to a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, field-theory, finite-fields

I am working on a following problem:

Construct a monomorphism $\phi: GL(1,4) \to GL(2,2)$ that
corresponds to the inclusion of $A_3$ in $S3$. (Recall that the field $\mathbb{F}_4$
of 4 elements can be written as $\{0, 1,\alpha, \alpha^2\}$, where $\alpha + 1 = \alpha^2$ and
$\lambda + \lambda = 0$ for all $\lambda \in \mathbb{F}_4$). Show further that the extension of $\phi$
to a map from $\mathbb{F}_4$ to $\mathcal{M}_2(\mathbb{F}_2$), where $\mathbb{F}_2 = {0, 1}$ is the field of 2
elements, is a monomorphism of rings.

Now for the first part I found the following map (considering $\mathbb{F}_4$ as a 2 dimensional VS over $\mathbb{F}_2$ with the basis $1,\alpha$):
$$1\mapsto 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$\alpha \mapsto 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\
1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$
$$\alpha^2 \mapsto 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1\\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

Is this correct?
Furthermore I don't see why the second part isn't trivial from the first one, that is if something is monomorphism of fields, how could anything go wrong if we just extend the codomain to include some additional elements, when we are still just mapping everything to a subring that is still a field?

Comment: You are told to construct a particular homomorphism from the multiplicative group of $\Bbb{F}_4$, you don't have any reason to assume it satisfies $\phi(a+b)=\phi(a)+\phi(b)$ when adding $\phi(0)=0$.

Comment: Indeed, the given a group morphism $\phi:G\to H$, there's no reason $\phi(a+b)=\phi(a)+\phi(b)$ for *any* $a$ or $b$. Of course you constructed it so that it will work for all $a,b\neq 0$, but you need to at least explain why that is (and also deal with the $0$ case).

Comment: Oh, right, silly me... I don't know why I was thinking about fields rather than groups to begin with. Thanks guys!